# active admin - Filters from right to left - Table Scroll bar - css/layout/structure changes

Tags: css, filter, ruby-on-rails-3.2, activeadmin

Im using active admin gem on Rails. I haven't gone through everything, yet.

2 clarifications:

```
1. I want to display the filters section(:id => "filters_sidebar_section") to my left hand side. By default, this is displayed to my right hand side.
2. Can I limit the table width, so that a scroll bar is displayed at the bottom of the table and if my table has like 30 columns, I can use the scroll bar to reach the 30th column(Like you used to read this entire question)?
```

Comment: care to explain why downvote?

Comment: I have been google searching this for the past 2 days.. I couldnt find an answer.. I posted it here and I get a downvote? This is insane!!

Comment: I didn't downvote, but people probably don't find it very cute to have to scroll horizontally just for you to illustrate a point.

Comment: I think you liked it..

Comment: Hi beck, I too have the same issue. How did you resolve.? I wanna have the filter values be displayed from right to left..

Answer (score 3):

this gem can halp you managing sidebar
https://github.com/Fivell/active_admin_sidebar

```
gem install active_admin_sidebar
```

easy change sidebar position with activeadmin (tested with activeadmin ~> 1.0.0.pre)

Add including of css file

```
@import "active_admin_sidebar";
```

to the app/assets/stylesheets/active_admin.css.scss

Changing sidebar position dynamically with before_filter

```
# app/admin/posts.rb
ActiveAdmin.register Post do
  before_filter :left_sidebar!, only: [:show]
end

# app/admin/comments.rb
ActiveAdmin.register Comment do
  before_filter :right_sidebar!
end
```

Moving sidebar to the left within all resource (config/initializers/active_admin.rb)

```
# == Controller Filters
#
# You can add before, after and around filters to all of your
# Active Admin resources from here.
#
config.before_filter do
  left_sidebar! if respond_to?(:left_sidebar!)
end
```

Disabling using sidebar layout on dashboards (if you setup sidebar position with initializer)

```
ActiveAdmin.register_page "Dashboard" do
  controller {skip_before_filter :left_sidebar!}
  #.....
end
```

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: @MathieuF, added detailed usage example